# How can I crop multiple areas in each frame of the video using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, pyffmpeg

For each frame I want to crop multiple areas using ffmpeg but I am not sure how to proceed.

This is what I have done to crop one part of the image,

```
fmpeg -i video.mp4 -filter:v "fps=1,crop=759:41:33:99,scale=128:44" %d.png
```

This is one frame of the video,

[image]

The above command crops the number one row or first position from the image. Likewise I want to crop all the positions or rows from this frame. I tried passing multiple crop statements but that doesn't seem to work. What else I can try?

Comment: What would you expect the outcome to look like? I mean you want multiple areas but there is just one image per frame as output to work with. Can't you simply post process the frame images generated by this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a crop per output. Example for rows 1 to 3:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -vf "fps=1,crop=759:41:33:99,scale=128:-1" 1_%03d.png -vf "fps=1,crop=759:41:33:155,scale=128:-1" 2_%03d.png -vf "fps=1,crop=759:41:33:209,scale=128:-1" 3_%03d.png
```

...and so on.